# Where to put initializer stuff on nextJs

Tags: next.js

I have a NextJS alongside NX app where I use firestore as BE.

I have `api` routes set but also some library that handle feature-based stuff. for example :

`initFirebaseAdmin`

```
export const initFirebaseAdmin = (config: admin.AppOptions): boolean => {
  try {
    if (!admin.apps.length) {
      admin.initializeApp({ ...config });
    }

    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    Sentry.captureException(e);
    return false;
  }
};

initFirebaseAdmin({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    clientEmail: process.env.NEXT_FIREBASE_ADMIN_PRIVATE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
    privateKey: process.env.NEXT_FIREBASE_ADMIN_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(
      /\\n/g,
      '\n'
    ),
  }),
});
```

`api/user/routes`

```
import '../initFirebaseAdmin';

export const GET = async (req: Request) => {
  const { error, user } = await isAuthenticated(req);
  if (!user) {
    return error;
  }

  const { searchParams } = new URL(req.url);
  const requestParams = readQueryString(searchParams);
  return getUsers(requestParams);
};
```

with a `lib/user/operation`

```
export async function placesGet(params) {
    let query: firestore.Query<firestore.DocumentData> = firestore().collection('users');
}
```

now, if I run my code trough a CSR component, all is fine, since I init firebase, etcetc.. but if I run this trough an SSR component, `initFirebaseAdmin` will never be called and firestore will say it s not initialized.

I would like my library to not care about environment variable, and how I setup firebase/firestore. So I wonder if there is a way in NextJs to have some initializer or other code run every time the server code is runned

Answer (score 0):

In Next.js, you can use a custom server to execute code on the server-side when it starts. This is helpful for running initialization code, such as setting up Firebase or other environment-related tasks

Comment: Is it really the recommended way ? https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/custom-server they clearly say that we should not need it and it doesnt sound something you would setup just to run an init script